# I can't ask any question

Tags: support, banned

I'm not able to ask any further questions on English language and usage while I just asked three questions and all of them are short and brief. Thus, whatever I do, nothing happens and I'm really confused about what I should do to gain this privilege back. I would really appreciate it if you indicate my problems there. I've done all sorts of things that the site wanted me to lift the ban.

Comment: So high-level feedback, from reading the Q and A I can see on your profile: you’d be better served by participating on [ell.se] than on EL&U. As for this meta-Q: can you edit it to tell us explicitly what sorts of things  you have done that the site wanted you to do, to lift the ban?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not the case that you have only asked three questions. The thirteen other questions which are now deleted also count towards the way the system calculates whether or not to accept any more questions. You will have seen a warning about post quality (although I'm not sure what that actually says).

Unfortunately, the number of deleted questions compared to the number of questions which remain will make it very difficult to correct the situation. You need to improve your deleted questions and get them undeleted (you should easily be able to undelete the ones you deleted yourself). They then need to be upvoted.

Because it's a system behaviour, there's a lot of advice on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) which it would be imprudent to reproduce here — the advice may change from time to time, and it's better to have it only in one place. However, your question here is useful as a pointer to others about where to find the information; and there is also relevant information in our own Help pages.

It's important to note that moderators cannot lift the ban: it's an automatic system thing, and you need to convince the system algorithm that your questions are good.

If you can't remove the ban by improving your existing questions, it will last six months*. But after that time, you will need to post good questions which can be upvoted. A downvoted question, and especially one which is deemed off-topic for lack of research or any other reason [like proof-reading, "Is this correct?"] will adversely affect your chances.

- Meta.SE: [What to do about a post ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997)
- ELU Help: [Why are questions no longer being accepted?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)
- ELU Help: [What's on topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- ELU Help: [What's a good question](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

While the ban on this site doesn't affect your ability to ask questions on other sites, it does stop your questions being migrated here if they are off-topic elsewhere. That will affect your question score on that site (because the question will have been downvoted and closed as off-topic). Questions about English are likely to be on-topic on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com), but that site's community have their own rules about what is on-topic and what form a question needs to take, which are very similar to this site's. Do check their [Help pages](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

---

*At least, our help pages say that. Meta.SE says it will never expire. In any case it's good practice to rectify what's wrong.

Comment: Re 6 months: the ban is more like an extreme throttle. The ban lasts indefinitely, but once every 6 months the user gets **one** shot at asking a question. If its reception is good enough to satisfy the algorithm (that is, if that one question *taken together with all the user’s other questions, deleted or not*, raise him into “well received” territory), the ban is lifted. Else he has to wait another 6 months for another “one shot”.