# question ban not lifted even after 6 months

Tags: support, closed-questions, banned

Last year I asked a few questions related to proofreading. I was a newbie and did not know about this question ban related thing. I have been wanting to ask one question from last one month but cannot ask due to question ban. Today I read about question ban and found that**after 6 months an account holder can get opportunity to ask new question.** Now my concern is that my question ban is more than 6 months old and I have not yet received my question. Please help.

Comment: Your questions seem well-received on ELL, and from what I can see in your history, the questions you’ve asked here, on ELU, are all better suited to ELL anyway. So what’s the interest in ELU? You get good answers on ELL; what’s missing?

Comment: @DanBron...I just think the quality of answers on ELU is much higher than that of ELL. Moreover, it just does not feel right to be banned. I am a non-native English learner and I want to keep an arsenal of resources to learn this language. Can you please upvote my last added question so that ban can be lifted.

Answer (score 6):

I can't tell when your question ban was imposed. It's an automated ban imposed by the system and moderators cannot do anything to change it.

I have found that you posted a question on March 25, after seeing a warning about the quality of past questions. You deleted that question after eight minutes, but — although I can't see when the ban was imposed — I suspect that that used the opportunity to post which is made available after six months.

(I put it like that because you stopped asking after eight poorly-received questions in May 2019. If that was when the ban started, then you would have been able to post in November 2019. You used that privilege in March 2020.)

Deleted questions count towards the quality calculation. This means that deleting downvoted questions cannot stave off the ban: those questions have still been asked. Your most recent question was neutral, not downvoted or upvoted; however, it was still posted.

Since you were able to post on March 25, the next opportunity will probably be on September 25.

More detail is available in [another Meta question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13542/i-cant-ask-any-question).

Comment: ..So I had only one option and that was to undelete my last asked question. So I have done that  and now I need some upvotes to get my ban lifted. I understand my question may not look like useful for the community. I have asked some good questions on the site in the past. So Sir, can the moderators help me by upvoting my this question. I will try to post quality questions in the future .Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Votes should be cast on the merit of the question, not on future promises, I'm afraid. Asking for upvotes to lift a ban is actually soliciting targeted votes (votes for the person, not the post). Please don't do that.

Comment: @SudhirSharma A better choice would be asking here for advice on how to improve the questions you've asked in the past so that they deserve to be up-voted. That way you get your ban lifted, you contribute to the community, and you learn how to avoid making the same mistakes in the future.

Comment: @ColleenV...Great advice.How can I ask for help? It would be thankful of you if you help me in editing those questions.

Comment: @SudhirSharma You might ask for advice in the [site's chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage-multi-layered-discourse-room) or post here on Meta about what can be done to fix a specific question. You should read all the feedback you've already received on those questions (for example, any information linked in the close reasons and notices about your question ban) so that you can ask for help on specific aspects. If you just ask for general help, a lot of people are probably just going to point you to the help/faq articles.